# Understanding Height with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a div height the length of its container. Right now I can only get it to fit the contents that are inside of it. Here is a screenshot to make it clear.

[image]

See how it cuts off. I don't want it to do that, I want it to dynamically fit the size it contains. So that the content will stay where it is but the background will stretch to the bottom.

Here is my Markup:

```
<div class="topic-body">
  <div class="topic-body__sidebar">
    <% Topic.all.each do |topic| %>
      <%= link_to topic.name, topic_path(topic.slug) %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="topic-body__navigation">
    <% if current_user.admin? %>
      <%= link_to "Add Navigation Item", new_topic_navigation_item_path(@topic.slug) %>
    <% end %>

    <% @topic.categories.each do |category| %>
      <h3><%= category.name %></h3>
      <div class="row">
        <% category.navigation_items.each do |navigation_item| %>
          <a href="<%= navigation_item.url %>" class="item">
            <% if navigation_item.thumbnail %>
              <%= image_tag(navigation_item.thumbnail.url, {class: "thumbnail"}) %>
            <% else %>
              <div class="stub thumbnail"></div>
            <% end %>
            <p><%= navigation_item.title %></p>
          </a>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
  .topic-body {
      width: 100%;

      &__sidebar {
        display: inline-grid;
        width: 15%;
        float: left;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-top: 30px;
        font-size: 18px;
        background-color: #F9F9F9;

        a {
          color: $table-text;
          padding: 6px 0;
        }
      }

      &__navigation {
        width: 80%;
        float: right;
      }
    }
```

Comment: have a look at flexbox.

Comment: Why have you got padding-left and padding-top? The green bits are the padding

Comment: padding is just for styles that's all.

Comment: Are you saying take the padding off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at all of the related elements and their padding. The green highlighting of your chrome inspector is indicating padding. If you set the `padding: 0px`, the element should fit the height (and width) of its container. If you want JUST the height, set

```
.topic-body__sidebar { padding-top: 0px; }
```